# how to get value param include TypeFilterAttribute in net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-8

I want get value param from action controller include TypeFilterAttribute
This is my code controller :

```
 [FileDocumentExistFilterAttribute(file: "fileDocument")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string fileDocument)
```

this is my code fillter :

```
public class FileDocumentExistFilterAttribute: TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public FileDocumentExistFilterAttribute(string file = null)
   : base(typeof(FileDocumentExistFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { file };
    }

}
```

I using net core 8 
thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ActionArguments property of the ActionExecutingContext object to get the parameters and corresponding values of the controller method,Here's an example you can use as a reference:

My FileDocumentExistFilter:

```
public class FileDocumentExistFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private readonly string _fileDocument;

    public FileDocumentExistFilter(string fileDocument)
    {
        _fileDocument = fileDocument;
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (context.ActionArguments.TryGetValue("fileDocument", out var fileDocumentValue))
        {
            
            var fileDocument = (string)fileDocumentValue;
            Console.WriteLine($"FileDocumentExistFilterAttribute - fileDocument value: {fileDocument}");
        }
        await next();
    }
}
```

My FileDocumentExistFilterAttribute:

```
  public class FileDocumentExistFilterAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
  {
      public FileDocumentExistFilterAttribute(string file = null)
          : base(typeof(FileDocumentExistFilter))
      {
          Arguments = new object[] { file };
      }
  }
```

My method:

```
[FileDocumentExistFilterAttribute(file: "fileDocument")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string fileDocument)
{     
        
    ViewBag.FileDocument = fileDocument;
         

    return View();
}
```

When I send data:

[image]

I can get the parameters and value:
[image]